# How to handle multiple broadcast and reply messages in Python

Tags: python-3.x, callback, python-asyncio

I know the Python GIL keeps one from using threads.

But suppose I want to have the following setup:

1) my computer (the host) wants to send the same message over the internet to 5-20 users; the message has a unique ID

2) each of them has 30 seconds to respond, if they care to, specifying the ID and some required info so I can match up broadcasts and responses

3) I fill in a data structure (whatever makes most sense) with the replies

4) I do what I need to with the replies I now have

The problem is I might need to do this every 5 seconds with differing messages (each with a unique ID), so suspending the main loop for 30 seconds isn't practical.

This i one of those times you'd like callbacks and threads.  Bu given this problem, how does one solve it in Python?

Answer (score 0):

> I know the Python GIL keeps one from using threads.

This premise is incorrect. The GIL doesn't keep you from using threads, it just doesn't allow more than one thread to execute Python code in parallel. They are serialized using a lock, and execution is occasionally preemptively switched from one thread to another. Your code is never aware of the switching, so for the purpose of implementing timeouts or reading from multiple sockets or databases etc. at once, [threads](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html) will work just fine.

Having said that, there **are** alternatives to threading well suited for concurrent IO communication, such as [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). If you have a concrete problem with asyncio, feel free to ask a question. But you don't have to use it just to avoid threads.